# BS4 find sub elements where parent class contains hijack

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Source page = http://bgpstream.com/

Section to parse:

```
<tr>
    <td class="event_type">Possible Hijack</td>
    <td class="country">          
</td>
<td class="asn">
    <i>Expected Origin AS:</i> TENETA, UA (AS 47725)<br>
    <i>Detected Origin AS:</i> LANFIBRA TELECOMUNICACOES - EIRELI, BR (AS 269684) 
</td>
    <td class="starttime"> 2021-02-28 15:13:14 </td>
    <td class="endtime">
</td>
    <td class="moredetail"> <a href="/event/268928">More detail</a></td>
</tr>
```

Trying something like this:

```
evts = soup.find_all('td', class_='event_type')
    for evt in evts:
        if('Hijack' in evt.text):
            asns = evt.find_all('asn')
            for a in asns:
                print(a)
```

However, playing with the elements I can't get the desired output.

I would like to get all "hijack" elements in any format csv, space delimited or line and matching a particular ASN.

For example one find any hijack with AS #### (in above format AS 47725):

```
Expected Origin AS: TENETA, UA (AS 47725)
Detected Origin AS: LANFIBRA TELECOMUNICACOES - EIRELI, BR (AS 269684)
2021-02-28 15:13:14
```

^ The last element is the start time

My thought was to get all td's with text containing Hijack then get sub elements where asn contains my AS ##### that I was looking for (python argument input) then it will return the three sub elements (child) for the one in the current element in the loop. However, I can't seem to get the child elements from the hijack evts collection. Any help for iterating the collection?

Answer (score 1):

The `find_all()` method [accepts a function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function). You can create a custom function to check if "Hijack" is in the class `event_type`, and check if the next class (`asn)` contains the desired "AS-XXX" you are looking for.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = "http://bgpstream.com/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content, "html.parser")


def filter_for_hijack():
    return (
        lambda element: element.name == "td"
        and "event_type" in element.get("class")
        and "Hijack" in element.text.strip()
        # You can specify 'AS-XXX' here
        and "AS 47725" in element.find_next(class_="asn").get_text(strip=True)
    )


for tag in soup.find_all(filter_for_hijack()):
    print(tag.find_next(class_="asn").get_text(strip=True, separator=" "))
```

Output:

```
Expected Origin AS: TENETA, UA (AS 47725) Detected Origin AS: LANFIBRA TELECOMUNICACOES - EIRELI, BR (AS 269684)
Expected Origin AS: TENETA, UA (AS 47725) Detected Origin AS: LANFIBRA TELECOMUNICACOES - EIRELI, BR (AS 269684)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:has` and `:-soup-contains` (or just `:contains` for earlier versions) to isolate the rows where there is a first child `td` containing your target word. A nested list comprehension, testing for `Tag` (else assuming `NavigableString`) can then generate the rows of a `DataFrame`. You can then filter and subset that `DataFrame` with pandas according to target columns and ASN:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag
import pandas as pd

asn = 'AS 1031'

r = requests.get('http://bgpstream.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
headers = [th.text for th in soup.select('#all_events th')]

df = pd.DataFrame([[td.get_text(' ').replace('\n','') if isinstance(td, Tag) else td for td in tr] for tr in soup.select('#all_events tr:has(td:nth-child(1):-soup-contains("Hijack"))')])

df2 = df[[1, 5, 7]]
df2.columns = ['Event type', 'ASN', 'Start time (UTC)']

print(df2[df2['ASN'].str.contains(f'{asn}')])
```

Thanks to @Nihilist for stating one can also use read_html to grab the table. You can then filter that:

```
df2 = pd.read_html('http://bgpstream.com/')[0]
print(df2[(df2['ASN'].str.contains(f'{asn}')) & (df2['Event type'].str.contains('Hijack'))])
```

Comment: `df = pd.read_html('http://bgpstream.com/')[0]` looks more simpler way

Comment: @Nihilist Thanks. Yeah, much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need `<td class="asn">` from each tr tag if `<td class="event_type">` contains Hijack.

**Using list comprehension**

```
trs = soup.find_all("tr")
tds_with_asn = [tr.find_all("td", class_="asn") for tr in trs if "Hijack" in tr.find("td", class_="event_type").text]
tds_with_your_asn = [i.text for i in tds_with_asn if "47725" in i.text]
```

**Another method using Pandas**

```
import pandas as pd

# Define ASN here
asn = 47725

df = pd.read_html('http://bgpstream.com/')[0]
df_filt = df.loc[(df['Event type'].str.contains("Hijack")) & (df['ASN'].str.contains(f"{asn}"))]
df_filt.to_csv('output.csv', index=False) #this will export final data to csv
```